# How do I attach a generated pdf by dompdf and mail it in phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to genearate a pdf and I need to attach it to phpmailer and mail it.
Help would be gladly appreciated.

```php
<?php
require_once("../../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$templateFile = 'prog_report.php';
$content = file_get_contents($templateFile);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($content);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

and this is the phpmailer attachement moudule..

```
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");
```

I want to attach the generated pdf here and the pdf should not be saved on the hard disk drive.

Comment: did u get answer to this question

Comment: yes , copy the pdf into a variable
$pdf=$dompdf->output();

and then attach it in the mail with the following code
$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, 'filename.pdf');

Comment: @Venkat : i need some info regarding php , any way i could contact u ? or find u on FB

Comment: You can contact me @venkatakrishnabtech@gmail.com .......or search me with that email id in Fb also

Answer (score 4):

no save file on disk :

```
$pdfString = $dompdf->output();
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfString, 'name file.pdf');
```

Comment: When proving an answer give some description why and how it is going to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First create pdf file in your server

Why dont you swap them round create the pdf first as a file and then stream the created file back ?

```
$file_to_save = '/home/stsnew/public_html/pdf/file.pdf';
//save the pdf file on the server
file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output());
```

and then it attach with mail.

Comment: well i don't want the file to be saved on the server .. on click of a button i want the pdf to be generated and mailed by phpmailer .

Comment: you not want to attach a file you want to send pdf file as content

Comment: tell me the exact way to attach it to a mail ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi mate I used fpdf library and php mailer and it works like charm try this.

```
require('fpdf.php');
$filename="bookingconfirmation.pdf";
//rest of pdf code here

$pdf->Output($filename);

include "libMail/class.phpmailer.php";
$m= new Mail; // create the mail
$m->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$m->Host = "mail.connectingauthors.com"; // SMTP server
$m->SetFrom("susan@connectingauthors.com");    
$m->AddReplyTo("pixelart@optonline.net");
$m->AddAddress("pixelart@optonline.net");
$m->Subject( "Connecting Authors Booking Confirmation" );
$m->MsgHTML( "HellonnPlease find attached ..." ); // set the body
$m->AddAttachment( $filename ) ;
$m->Send(); // send the mail
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the FAQs at DomPDF's wiki http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ try

`$pdf = $dompdf->output();`

instead of

```
$pdf = $dompdf->stream('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by myself using the code bellow:

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($pass_doc_path))
```

And its working for me.

Many Thanks